Is my Battery or Alternator the problem?
I have been having weak start issues lately in my 2000 Toyota Camry and recently left the radio on for no more than 5 minutes with the car not running only to be unable to start again.
After diagnosing with a battery tester my once 600CCA 60Ah battery is sitting at 495CCA 12.4v now upon a full charge using a battery charger. The tester shows battery health at 71%.
My alternator output voltage will not go higher than 13.6v no matter the RPM of the engine when measured between the battery terminals, as well as the alternator +ve and negative battery terminal. If I measure the +ve side of the alternator to the body of the alternator itself I get approximately 14.5v but again only see 13.6v when using the negative of the battery. My battery tester is showing the charging system to be slightly under the green OK mark.
In my mind the battery seems fine, possible the alternator regulator is the issue. If someone with more brainpower than me would be able to share some knowledge it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How old is the battery?

I'm deeply suspicious of your battery tester giving a false "good enough" reading. Use a carbon pile tester and put an actual 300 amp load on the battery, which it should be able to maintain for 15 seconds if good. I suspect it won't do 300 amps for more than 2 seconds and voltage will immediately drop to 8-10 volts under load, indicating "game over" for this battery.

It sounds like you're on the right track. The symptoms suggest your battery is weak and may not hold a charge well, especially given its reduced capacity and health. The alternator's inconsistent voltage could indicate a failing regulator. Consider replacing the battery and checking the alternator regulator to resolve the issue.
